# Creation of socket takes too long sometimes. > 30 sec on Android

Tags: android, sockets, tcp

I'have noticed that sending of message from one device to other can take long time.
After deep investigation was defined that, place where socket created on sender side takes all time.

```
    InetAddress serverAddr = InetAddress.getByName(serverIpAddress);
    socket = new Socket(serverAddr, Constant.PORT_COMMANDS_MULTICAST);
```

I know, that network is serious source of problems, but 30 sec for simple socket connection looks like very long.
Note: during other testings it can get only 1 second, but often gets 10, 15 and even 30 second.

Can some one describe solution for improving of speed.

Comment: Do you mean it takes a long time to *succeed*, or a long time to *fail*? A TCP connect should succeed almost immediately, if it succeeds at all.

Comment: If you want to go with library than apache mina library is best for socket application, even i am using apache mina library for chating application.

Comment: @Avi Do you have some reason for thinking that will change the behaviour concerned?

Comment: @Avi I didn't ask you what Apache Mina is. I am asking you whether you have a cogent reason for thinking it will solve this problem. Which in turn implies that (a) you know what this problem is, (b) that you know that Apache Mina solves it, and therefore (c) that Apache Mina does not use `InetAddress` or `new Socket(...)`. (c) is certainly false, and therefore (b), and it is therefore reasonable to believe that (a) is false as well.

Comment: @EJP. I mean, long time to succeed. It just stops on line where new Socket creates and wait there for 1-30 sec. Then all other work goes immediately. (sending of message, closing)

Comment: That will usually be due to a DNS misconfiguration. Investigate with `nslookup` from the client host.

Comment: @EJP thanks. will look on this.

Comment: Usually those long times are due to the name resolution (DNS) , especially if you put a non-existent hostname or the DNS server is down, try with a numeric IP and you'll see how much less it takes.

Comment: @Tonteria24 Do you mean using of other way of InetAddress.        byte[] ipAddr = new byte[] {
                    (byte)192, (byte)168, (byte)5, (byte)71
            };
InetAddress serverAddr = InetAddress.getByAddress(ipAddr); ?

Comment: InetAddress serverAddr = InetAddress.getByName("192.168.1.71");

Comment: @Tonteria24 Long DNS times result from DNS servers being down or misconfigured. A non-existent hostname shouldn't by itself cause a long DNS time.

Comment: @ДмитроЯковлєв Did you find out what it was?